# scroll view and expandable list view

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I am working in project there the view like about first five view Static and below to that i have expandable list (ie 9:00-10:30) if click on that i will open the slots i can default scroll the expandable list to see slots but my device having very less space to scroll. Because of i kept scroll for entire layout that time entire screen is not scrolling.  help any one. I was done some many scenarios but i was not get this. if want scroll entire view what should i do.can any one help out from this . thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
you take that time in spinner , so that you can see the entire view
```

Comment: 09:00-10:30 is expandable list view.

Answer (score 0):

As your first 5 views are static, you can use `ListView` `addHeaderView` method to add all your static views at the top of listview. 
Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) for addHeaderView. Hope this helps.

**Edit:** Adding header view to ListView

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.xml_file, null);
listview.addHeaderView(view);

listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: How can i add 5 static view to listview

Comment: Have u gone through that link? If u have not, go through that link. Its about header and footer views for ListView.

Comment: I was gone through that one but i am getting classCast Excepiton i am adding like expandableListView.addHeaderView(edtContactNo);
  expandableListView.addHeaderView(tV_existingPatient);

Comment: I have edited my answer. Check it out. Place all your widgets(5 static views) in a xml file and inflate that xml file as in code.

Comment: But I have one one constraint All 5 view are same list xml. like sheduleappointment.xml having 5 view and below to that expandable list.That time how can i inflate

Comment: Take those 5 views in a separate xml file. Keep that listView to full screen in main xml file. Now inflate that 5 view xml file and set as header to listView. In main xml file, listView may seem empty but when you add header view and set adapter to listView, by default all those 5 views will be on top of listView

Comment: I tried this but it's showing blank.
  ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_expadable, null , false);
 
  istView.addHeaderView(view , null ,false);

Comment: I don't know whats wrong in your case but that above edited answer is from my project and its working fine for me. Anyway try to do same as above... take addHeaderView with only 1 argument. Hope it helps.